# Is it possible to display my iphone LIVE on desktop or macbook, and use the mouse to click?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, mouse

Is it possible to display my iphone LIVE on desktop or macbook, and use the mouse to click?

For example if I need to click with my mouse on an app etc?

Thank you

Comment: You can use a simulator with Xcode to get this, but that's not *your* iPhone.

Comment: There are 3rd-party applications that allow you to see your iPhone on your desktop live, but you can't click the icons because it's just a video of your screen.

Comment: no you can't do that, however you can copy your iPhone screen to your computer with quicktime or third party applications